# Program value into edit text box GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am making a GUI in Matlab and am trying to incorporate two different codes into the same GUI to analyze a set of data taken from an Excel file. How do I display the result from my first code, being just a single value, into an edit text box. I've tried messing with a string but have not had much luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you tried? This should be pretty straigtforward.

Comment: Agreed with Ander, plus why the "android-edittext" tag? Is this Matlab + Android or Matlab-only?

Comment: is the result from your first code a numeric value or a string ? Have you read the documentation [text uicontrol properties](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#zmw57dd0e728137) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, all of them depending on the structure of the GUI yuo've built.

One possibility could be:

you have a pushbutton: when the user pushes it, the `pushbutton callback` calls your first script which stores the result in a variable, say `out_var` (you should have inserted in the callback either directly the code or the call to a function / ".m" file)

Your GUI has a `static text uicontrol` in which you want to write the value of "`out_var`" (it is better using "static text" uicontrol rather than "edit text" uicontrol just to show a string being the first "not editable").

To display the value of "out_var" in the "static text" uicontrol, you can insert the following code in the pushbutton callback:

```
set(handles.text1,'string',num2str(out_var));
```

where "text1" is the handle of the static text uicontrol.
You can "find" its name inspecting the static text uicontrol properties with the GUIDE tool looking for the "Tag" property.

Hope this helps.